# How to get formatted json from curl request?

Tags: php, json

I use this code to return Google API places data:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

include_once 'configuration.php';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key='.API_KEY);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json')
);

$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo $result;
```

but I get unformatted data like this:

> { "html_attributions" : [], "next_page_token" :
>   "CpQCBgEAAPvFBhJiIaT9iMCS-miiTKEXeY0Gkdt3psd0DiGaza6x7U_NCaLCCoc6avQy7_VepOtrke7oIfrXC2MFkeDmD2DJt3Hi5j4IEmHyY9lTT0JkvRRLW043khKMhAiz6U5fdG-Ylkp7Uq3E_jWjOjgSoR7sBbTzVcn_PuzeKcRcwHtyV2h-ZpCwY-YH7wBiKogPvrwQYCWN_scs5ZWsoJSgELFFFfvl-oaL6OXCERv1fZM6opKvri1GMK6_aEYjnj4pR92PjJNWaAeroixITFGoj5RDVS4MNPVd-60jdG83ET0JU-XsjiY7TdipReos7gbKQR8eJXZho11sOLKGtTATOVCzPZYpzsbvjFgpzMzAoyEFEhCtyjb8l0hKpZAXk7rKoe4NGhSVJjiMIqDyQPH0hVYJg-IX1p2Rvw",
>   "results" : [ { "formatted_address" : "529 Kent St, Sydney NSW 2000,
>   Australia", "geometry" : { "location" : { "lat" : -33.875154, "lng" :
>   151.204976 }, "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : -33.87374772010728, "lng" : 151.2065219798927 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : -33.87644737989272, "lng" : 151.2038223201073 } } }, "icon" :
>   "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restau

I need to get in this format:

[image]

Comment: formatting only benefit when testing, on actual code, you don't care if it is beauty or not as long as the data is there. You only care how to read the JSON to makes use of its data.

Comment: That being said, we as developer usually just copy the outputted JSON and paste it to our preferred JSON reader to read the data as humanely as posible

Comment: on browser, I usually use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: When I put the Google API url into the browser directly it display formatted json into tabs like the picture above but my php code display it as bunch of text ! is that ok to pass these data to mobile developer without formatting ?

Comment: That's the browser's doing, the actual result is not formatter. `is that ok to pass these data to mobile developer without formatting` >> That's what we (api developer) usually do. Just return whatever JSON data without format.

Comment: thanks alot ariefbayu but why the browser does not format my data ?

Comment: some browser format JSON data (based on HTTP header returned by server), while the other just display whatever JSON string is returned by server.

Comment: When I want to print JSON for debug, etc. I grab it, run `json_decode()` on it, then re-convert back with `json_encode()`.  Then replace `},{` so there is a newline after the comma, and then print the result